# Android Play Store installs previous version of app in Alpha

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I have an Android app in alpha testing; I have uploaded updated APKs a few times. My testers report that they still get the previous version, not the latest one, even though the Developer Console says the latest version is the right one - the latest I uploaded a few days ago - and doesn't say "Processing update" any more.

Is there anything I should advise my testers to do on their devices, and can I do something at my end?

Comment: They are downloading it from playstore or you are sending them any link by email??

Comment: Did you updated the version-number?

Comment: @jankigadhiya - From the Play Store. They are in a Closed Testing list.

Comment: @cherry-wave Yes, I did.

Comment: how did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install the latest public version of an app either, even after the alpha testing program for that app was ended. Then I manually left the testing program by going to the link where had I registered as a tester in the beginning.

In my app's case, the link was
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/np.com.naya.pasal

**Mind** to put your ***app id*** instead of *np.com.naya.pasal* in the above link

Your testers will get message like this when they have left the test. After a while they can install the latest version.
[image: Your testers will get this message when they have left the test.]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install old version of the app, then

1. Uninstall the app if you have already installed.
2. Then go to Google Play console > App bundle explorer. From there select app version and there you can see Shareable link to the app in Downloads tab. From that link you can install that specific app version.